# Problems with Identity.TwoFactorRememberMe and updated user SecurityStamp

Tags: asp.net-identity-3

After signing in using two-factor with authenticator app, I set rememberClient to true like this:

```
await _signInManager.TwoFactorAuthenticatorSignInAsync(code: request.Code,
                                                       isPersistent: request.IsPersistent,
                                                       rememberClient: request.RememberClient);
```

Signing in works fine and I get the `.AspNetCore.Identity.Application` and `Identity.TwoFactorRememberMe` cookies. If I sign out and in again I don't need to use two-factor. So long everything is fine.

The problem is when I do some changes in the user, like the phone number, and the SecurityStamp is changed. After the change is made I use `await _signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(user)`. But the `Identity.TwoFactorRememberMe` cookie isn't updated. This results in two problems:

1. The next time I sign in I have to use the two-factor authentication again.
2. During the same session, if I check if the user has remembered the browser, using `await _signInManager.IsTwoFactorClientRememberedAsync(user)`, it will result in an error "Failed to validate a security stamp" and the `.AspNetCore.Identity.Application` will be removed.

I've tried to renew the `Identity.TwoFactorRememberMe` cookie at the same time as the `.AspNetCore.Identity.Application` cookie, like this:

```
await base.RefreshSignInAsync(user);
await RememberTwoFactorClientAsync(user);
```

It works, but it will also set the `Identity.TwoFactorRememberMe` cookie for those who didn't have it before. I can't check if it is set before, because then I get the error I described in (2) above.

The next thing I will try is to do something like this for every place I do something which changes the user SecurityStamp:

```
var isTwoFactorClientRemembered = await _signInManager.IsTwoFactorClientRememberedAsync(user);

// do the changes...

await _signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(user);
if (isTwoFactorClientRememberedAsync)
    await _signInManager.RememberTwoFactorClientAsync(user);
```

Is there something I'm missing here, or is this the only way to go?

I'm using IdentityServer4 and a SPA app, but I don't believe that has anything to do with the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up adding a method in my custom ApplicationSignInManager:

```
public async Task<TResult> KeepSignInAsync<TResult>(ApplicationUser user, Func<Task<TResult>> func)
{
    var isTwoFactorClientRemembered = await IsTwoFactorClientRememberedAsync(user);

    var result = await func();

    await RefreshSignInAsync(user);

    if (isTwoFactorClientRemembered)
        await RememberTwoFactorClientAsync(user);

    return result;
}
```

When I change something which will update the user SecurityStamp I use it like this:

```
var result = await _signInManager.KeepSignInAsync(user, () => _userManager.SetPhoneNumberAsync(user, phoneNumber));
```